# WPF printing - PrintableAreaWidth & Height stuck in landscape?

Tags: wpf, printing

I'm printing a `FlowDocument` using the following code:-

```
var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
var result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
if (!result.Value)
{
    return;
}

var pageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
var pageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;

flowDoc.ColumnWidth = pageWidth;
flowDoc.PageWidth = pageWidth;
flowDoc.PageHeight = pageHeight;

var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDoc).DocumentPaginator;
printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Name");
```

The print dialog shows the page as being A4 Portrait, however the values of `printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth` and `.PrintableAreaHeight` are 1122 & 793 respectively, i.e.  *landscape*.

Changing the orientation or the paper size via the dialog has no effect on these values. What's going on?

**Update**
I've added a screenshot showing the `PrintDialog` properties. Notice how the PrintTicket property reflects the correct page size and orientation, yet the two PrintableArea... properties are the wrong way around.

I'm starting to think this is a "funny" with the printer/driver. I've tried printing to the "XPS Document Writer" printer, and the pages render correctly when I view the created file. (And if I view the PrintDialog's properties, the PrintableArea... properties correctly reflect an A4 portrait page).

[image]